# Can't downgrade bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, bundler

I try to install a project I cloned. When I do 'bundle install' I have the following message:

```
$ bundle install
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
In Gemfile:
rails (= 3.0.0) ruby depends on
bundler (~> 1.0.0) ruby

Current Bundler version:
bundler (1.6.2)

This Gemfile requires a different version of Bundler.
Perhaps you need to update Bundler by running `gem install bundler`?
```

So i did the following:

```
gem uninstall bundler
gem install bundler --version '1.0.0'
Successfully installed bundler-1.0.0
1 gem installed
```

I do 'bundle install', and I keep having the same message:

```
$ bundle install
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
In Gemfile:
rails (= 3.0.0) ruby depends on
bundler (~> 1.0.0) ruby

Current Bundler version:
bundler (1.6.2)

This Gemfile requires a different version of Bundler.

Perhaps you need to update Bundler by running `gem install bundler`?
```

It seems that I cannot downgrade bundler to the '1.0.0' version, any idea?

Answer (score 4):

If you do not need multiple versions of Bundler, you can uninstall the newer version:

```
$ gem uninstall bundler -v 1.6.2
```

You can also choose from a list of bundler versions if you have more than one:

```
$ gem uninstall bundler
```

Comment: This doesn't work for newer versions of rvm, which don't let you uninstall bundler.  I followed this comment to downgrade rvm and then downgrade bundler: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/8717#issuecomment-342753918

Comment: Gem bundler-1.6.2 cannot be uninstalled because it is a default gem

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to hit the global instance (alter installed ruby version as needed) --

```
$ gem uninstall -i /Users/<user>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8@global bundler
```